# Bug with comments posted via Android app

Tags: bug, comments, android-app

When users post from the Android app, the system adds a "via SE Android Mobile" tag to the comment, like the highlighted message below:

[image]

The problem is that the message only appears on mouseover/hover. It's there for both the first and second comments in the image, but only the hovered comment shows it. So, there's a huge and awkward gap between the time ("4 hours ago") and the "edit" link for any non-hovered comments posted via the app.

This image is from [meta.ebooks.stackexchange.com](https://ebooks.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/163/anyone-interested-in-creating-a-bot-for-the-chat-room); I have not yet been able to find instances of it on other sites.

Comment: This appears to be fixed now, although no one ever chimed in on this post...

Comment: Cannot be reproduced anymore. It seems SE devs removed the tag altogether on the comment.